# State base routing or abstract route with state in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm working on migration of existing angularjs application to Angular 6. I am trying to think on how to achieve `ui-router` abstract state feature in angular router. As per my understanding I don't think Angular router has feature for defining router state. We can only have url based router and the problem is I can not make any change to existing application URL.

I want to handle it for my login screens. I've states like `user` as abstract where it loads template having different `ui-view` declared in it. I've child state of this as `user.doLogin` and `user.register`.

Can anyone please give some direction or guidence on what is the best way to achieve this in Angular without changing url?

Comment: You can control which components render based entirely on state without changing the URL.

Comment: Is it possible to have abstract state which has no URL and having one component in it? Its child state have URL and component both but while loading child state it should call parent abstract state component. Any idea how to achieve?

Comment: Components react to state, and components communicate with each other via state. URL locations shouldn't have any bearing on what state is being communicated.